# Differentiate/decorate the command line input and output (with color or indentation)

Tags: bash, centos, colors, output

In a CentOS bash, (or, if there is a general way in other bashes, like Ubuntu, better), how can I differentiate commands typed by me with the output of the commands?

I ask this because when I use a command who outputs a lot in the screen, it is hard to find where it starts. I want to, for example, decorate my commands with a bright color and the output with a darker color, or, indent the output by 4.

Which may be like:

```
[root@westerngun ~]# ps aux | grep myname                             <- brighter
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   <- darker
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Or:

```
[root@westerngun ~]# ps aux | grep myname                          
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  <- indented by 4
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question: Don't do general work at an interactive root prompt, please.

Comment: Maybe it's not what you want but... would it help if you just piped the output to `less`? E.g. `ps aux | grep myname | less`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `bash` is `bash`, no matter where it's running.  The only important thing to note is which version.  `bash` 4 has some new features not available in `bash` 3 for instance.

That said, you can colorize up your prompt fairly easily by setting `PS1` ("Prompt String 1") to set one command apart from another.  For instance, when I log in on one of my home machines, I see this:

[image: Example Prompt]

When scrolling through my terminal history, I can just key off of the cyan text in my prompt to know when one command ends and another begins.

For reference, my `PS1` is as follows:

```
\[\e[38;5;14m\]\u\[\e[38;5;8m\]@\[\e[38;5;6m\]\h\[\e[38;5;8m\]:\[\e[38;5;10m\]\w \e[31m${?##0}\n\[\e[$(((($?>0))*31))m\]\$\[\e[0m\]
```

This shows my username, hostname, and CWD in a string which I could copy and paste into (e. g.) an `scp` command, followed by the exit code of the previous command if it was not zero.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is `zsh` or some other thing? The coloring settings seems a maze to me....

Comment: `zsh` is another shell; it fills the same role as `bash`, `sh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, and other shells.  Which shell one uses is very much a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Found these sites useful: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-command-prompt--net-20586 and https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: Very useful... I dig a little bit about the PS1 coloring and found what I need, thanks! Now I decorate my PS1 with this: `export PS1='[\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]\n-> '`. That is: `[green username@green hostname yellow_pwd] line_feed -> space`